# Mean of quarters belonging to each year in R

Tags: r, mean

I am using R, trying to find the mean for each year where every year has data for 4 quarters.

I begin by scraping the data from online, converting the data to a time series object, selecting the time frame I want, converting to an xts object, then using the  `apply.yearly()` function.

```
library(rvest)
library(xts) 
library(magrittr)

inflation <- html("http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/indicators/capacity-and-inflation-pressures/inflation/historical-data/")

data1 <- inflation %>%  
html_nodes("td:nth-child(2)") %>%  
html_text() %>%  
as.numeric() %>%  
rev() %>%  #reverses the order of the vector  
na.omit() %>%  
ts(frequency = 4, start = c(1993,1))`  

clean_canada <- window(data1, 2000, c(2014,4)) %>%  #selects a window starting at 2000, ending at period 4 of 2014
as.xts() %>%
apply.yearly(mean)
```

However, this seemingly generates a rolling average of every 4 quarters instead of generating one average for every calendar year. Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Perhaps this helps `window(data1, 2000, c(2014,4))  %>% as.xts() %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(grp = row.names(.)) %>% summarise(Mean=mean(V1))`

Comment: If you want yearly mean, `window(data1, 2000, c(2014,4))  %>% as.xts() %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(grp = sub('\\s+.*', '', row.names(.))) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(V1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to check whether we get a rolling average by using `apply.yearly`.  Convert the 'xts' object to `data.frame`, use the traditional group by 'year' and `summarise` to get the `mean`.

```
library(dplyr)
window(data1, 2000, c(2014,4)) %>%
          as.xts() %>%
          as.data.frame() %>% 
          group_by(grp = sub("\\s+.*", '', row.names(.))) %>% 
          summarise(Mean=mean(V1))
#   grp  Mean
#   (chr) (dbl)
#1   2000 1.300
#2   2001 2.100
#3   2002 2.300
#4   2003 2.200
#5   2004 1.600
#6   2005 1.550
#7   2006 1.975
#8   2007 2.125
#9   2008 1.675
#10  2009 1.775
#11  2010 1.725
#12  2011 1.725
#13  2012 1.700
#14  2013 1.250
#15  2014 1.800
```

The `apply.yearly` will also give the same output except that the `index` returned will be the last quarter for a particular year.  It is not doing any rolling average and is mentioned in the description

> Details: Simple mechanism to apply a function to non-overlapping time
>   periods, e.g. weekly, monthly, etc. Different from rolling functions
>   in that this will subset the data based on the specified time period
>   (implicit in the call), and return a vector of values for each period
>   in the original data.

```
window(data1, 2000, c(2014,4)) %>% 
          as.xts() %>%
          apply.yearly(mean)
#       [,1]
#2000 Q4 1.300
#2001 Q4 2.100
#2002 Q4 2.300
#2003 Q4 2.200
#2004 Q4 1.600
#2005 Q4 1.550
#2006 Q4 1.975
#2007 Q4 2.125
#2008 Q4 1.675
#2009 Q4 1.775
#2010 Q4 1.725
#2011 Q4 1.725
#2012 Q4 1.700
#2013 Q4 1.250
#2014 Q4 1.800
```

Comment: The first method you shared works for me. However the second method, the one I was using gives me different results...              [,1]
2000 Q1 1.300000
2001 Q1 1.425000
2002 Q1 2.175000
2003 Q1 2.525000
2004 Q1 1.775000
2005 Q1 1.700000
2006 Q1 1.550000
2007 Q1 2.125000
2008 Q1 1.900000
2009 Q1 1.800000
2010 Q1 1.800000
2011 Q1 1.550000
2012 Q1 1.925000
2013 Q1 1.500000
2014 Q1 1.250000
2014 Q4 1.966667

Comment: @EliasAyoub  The 2nd method is exactly the same one you showed in the post.  Can you try `as.xts() %>% xts::apply.yearly(mean)` in case the function got masked by some other functions.

Comment: @EliasAyoub I am using `xts_0.9-7`, `dplyr_0.4.3`, in case the version has anything to do with this.

Comment: Tried using that variant but I still get the same output I got before. I also noticed my index returned is the first quarter of every year while yours outputs the fourth quarter of every year. Also my last two observations seem confusing. I am using the latest version of both those packages.

Comment: @EliasAyoub I am not sure what might  be the problem as it is not reproducible to me.  You can try the first option then..

Comment: Yes I'm gonna stick to using the first one. Do you mind explaining what the `group_by(grp = sub('\\s+.*',' ', ` portion of the code does?

Comment: @EliasAyoub   It matches one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by characters until the end of the string (`.*`) and replace it with `''` so as to extract only the year part.